# How to change $PATH for crontab in Opensuse

Tags: linux, cron, opensuse, path

I have a script written which works perfect on terminal however gives error when called through crontab. It took me a while that the problem is with the cron environment not my script.

so I tried few options after reading various posts online:

`* * * * * PATH=/home/sam/bin:/home/sam/scriptbin/ /path/to/script`
           Didn't work

`* * * * * bash -lc /path/to/script` Didn't work

`* * * * * /path/to/script` Didn't work

How can I change `$PATH` variable for crontab in OPENSUSE or include in cron file so that it works. I am using open suse 11.

Here are few other things i tried:

```
PATH=/home/sdcme/afnibin:/sbin:/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/bin:/home/sdcme/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/opt/kde3/bin

11 9-19 * * * /home/sdcme/Final_concat_sdcme &> ~/concat.log  Didnt work

11 9-19 * * * /home/sdcme/Final_concat_sdcme.py &> ~/concat.log  didnt work
```

Thanks!

Comment: @lain i have tried almost all things mentioned in suggested post by you.. would be great if you can open this question.. ?